# Creating row and column as per no. of images coming dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to dynamically create a table using jQuery, JavaScript and HTML. In my application images are coming dynamically.

**CASE:**If 9 images are coming dynamically then there must 3 rows and 3 columns, and if 16 image coming then 4 rows and 4 columns and so on. I also want some solution if odd number images(eg: 17, 19, 91..etc). I have searched lot but I didn't got proper answer. I am not looking for plugins.

Comment: It would help if we knew how are you creating tables? Proper html table, or do you simply need a grid of images? Are the images the same size always or to they need to fill the contaier?

Comment: @Slavenko Miljic: I am creating table with help of html.

Comment: need to define criteria more. If 400 images does that mean 20 columns? Or is there a maximum? Can you float the elements? Or are you stuck with using an actual table? WHat determines length? Are you loading json data...post some code

Comment: Guys I don't need code. i just need to know the logic. For the know just consider image is coming dynamically and row and column must expand as per requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I'm not sure if this is what you wanted since your question is vague, no one has any idea how your markup looks like or how are you getting the images but I guess one of the solutions might be something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Udf3D/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = $("#container img").size();
   var columns = Math.sqrt(count);
   columns = parseInt(columns);        
    $("#container img").css('width', $("#container").width() / columns);

});
```

The idea is to get the number of images, find square root of that number and then simply set the width of the image to fit nicely in the container. (if you have 25 images, you'll have 5 columns and image width would be 1/5 of the contaier width).

Again no idea if this fits your needs but it's a direction in which I would go.

Comment: Thanks for effort(+1).In my case image which is coming dynamically has fixed width and same for all image. I just want to now how we will create the row ans column depending upon no. of images.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility that assumes fixed with of images. This means as the number of images gets large, you may go over the edge of the page. Maybe that is ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/C4WpQ/14/

[image]

```
function createImages (n)
{
    var images = [];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var imageUrl = "http://images.fake.com/" + i + ".png"; 
        images.push(imageUrl);
    }
    return images;
}

function leastSquareRoot (n)
{
    // maybe use ceil if you want a wider rectangle vs a taller one 
    // when a square is not possible
    var sr = Math.sqrt(n);
    return Math.floor(sr);
}

function createRowsAndCols (images, width)
{
    var result = "<table>\n";
    var lsr = leastSquareRoot(images.length);    
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % width == 0)
        {
            result += "\t<tr>\n";
        }

        result += "\t\t<td><img src=\"" + images[i] + "\"></td>\n";

        if (i % width == width - 1 || i == images.length - 1)
        {
            result += "\t</tr>\n";
        }
    }
    result += "</table>\n";
    return result;
}

function showTags(markup)
{
    return markup.replace(/\</g, '&lt;').replace(/\>/g, '&gt;');
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#canvas").html("Creating images...");
    var images = createImages(17);
    $("#canvas").append(" created " + images.length + " images.<br/>");
    var width = leastSquareRoot(images.length);
    $("#canvas").append("The proposed width is " + width + ".<br/>" );
    var result = createRowsAndCols(images, width);
    $("#canvas").append(result);
    $("#canvas").append("<pre><code>" + showTags(result) + "</code></pre>");
});
```